# Vue create proxy hook on base hook API

Tags: vue.js, vue-composition-api

I'm trying to create proxy on some hook API. In below example base hook is useUser and it's proxed by useUserProxy.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-if="user">
      <button @click="viewChangeEmail">Change email</button>
      <div>User email: {{ user.email }}</div>
      <button @click="viewLogout">Logout</button>
    </div>
    <div v-else>
      <button @click="viewLogin">Login</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import {onMounted, onUpdated, computed, ref} from 'vue'

function useUser() {
  const user = ref(null);

  function login(email, password) {
    user.value = {
      email,
      password,
      data: {}
    }
  }

  function logout() {
    user.value = null
  }

  function changeEmail(newEmail) {
    if (user.value) {
      user.value.email = newEmail;
    }
  }

  function setData(data) {
    if (user.value) {
      user.value.data = data;
    }
  }

  return {
    user,
    login,
    logout,
    changeEmail,
    setData,
  }
}

class UserProxy {
  constructor(email) {
    this.email = email;
  }
}

class Credentials {
  constructor(email, password) {
    this.email = email;
    this.password = password;
  }
}

function useUserProxy() {
  const {user: baseUser, login: baseLogin, logout: baseLogout, changeEmail: baseChangeEmail} = useUser();
  const user = computed(() => {
    if (baseUser.value) {
      new UserProxy(baseUser.value.email)
    }

    return baseUser.value;
  });

  function login(credentials) {
    baseLogin(credentials.email, credentials.password);
  }

  function changeEmail(newEmail) {
    baseChangeEmail(newEmail);
  }

  function logout() {
    baseLogout();
  }

  return {
    user,
    login,
    logout,
    changeEmail
  }
}

const {user, login, logout, changeEmail} = useUserProxy();

function viewLogin() {
  const email = new Date().toISOString();
  const credentials = new Credentials(email, "password");

  login(credentials);
}

function viewLogout() {
  logout();
}

function viewChangeEmail() {
  const newEmail = new Date().toISOString();

  changeEmail(newEmail)
}

onMounted(() => {
  console.log("onMounted user:", (user), user.value);
})

onUpdated(() => {
  console.log("onUpdated user:", (user), user.value);
})
</script>

<style scoped></style>
```

I got problem when it's comes to proxy ref objects from base hook e.g.

```
const user = ref(null);
```

to

```
const user = computed(() => {
  if (baseUser.value) {
    new UserProxy(baseUser.value.email)
  }

  return baseUser.value;
});
```

When my code looks like this I still getting original value in component instead of UserProxy.
When I change my code to

```
const user = computed(() => {
  if (baseUser.value) {
    new UserProxy(baseUser.value.email)
  }

  return null;
});
```

view doen't refresh.

When I change it to

```
const user = computed(() => new UserProxy(baseUser.value?.email));
```

I changing behaviour of the base API, null is now represent by some object.

It's possible to create such proxy in Vue without losing reactivity? Or should I create proxy on refs using something different then computed?

Comment: You don't return a value here `(baseUser.value) {
    new UserProxy`

Comment: Thanks for catch! No it's working correctly, I'm wondering it's
```
  const user = computed(() => {
    if (baseUser.value) {
      return new UserProxy(baseUser.value.email)
    }

    return baseUser.value;
  });
```
correct implementation on such proxy?

Comment: when I testing app behaviour with changing reference to object e.g.
`
  function changeUserToRandom() {
    user.value = {
          email: new Date().toDateString(),
          password: new Date().toDateString(),
          data: {}
        }
  }
`
with
`
  const user = computed(() => {
    if (baseUser.value) {
      return new UserProxy(baseUser.value.email)
    }

    return baseUser.value;
  });
`
component didnt update

Comment: Can you provide a way to reproduce the problem? It needs to be debugged. I don't see other problems besides the one I mentioned. UserProxy is not reactive but this doesn't seem to cause issues here

Comment: I created simple app that reproduces this problem - https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-g61xbm?file=src/App.vue, after login when u press "Change email" component will update properly, but when you press "Change user to random" component didnt update

Comment: This isn't shown in the question. You call `useUser` two times here, second time inside useUserProxy. This results in two different unrelated `user` states.

Comment: I added example with changeUserToRandom to check if everythink I working correctly after using  ``` const user = computed(() => { if (baseUser.value) { return new UserProxy(baseUser.value.email) } return baseUser.value; }); ```. I removed problem with using useUser two times but problem still exist

Comment: sorry worked now, I forgot to export changeUserToRandom from setup

Comment: Is this correct implementation of proxy in Vue?

Comment: Yes, looks like that. Btw "proxy" term is misleading here because it commonly refers to native Proxy in the context of Vue reactivity